# Gauge will find steps when steps are in multiple directories

Tags: python, getgauge

I cannot get the setup of having step implementions in more than one directory to work. I'm setting up my `env/python.properties` file according to documentation as this:

```
GAUGE_PYTHON_COMMAND = python3

\# Comma seperated list of dirs. path should be relative to project root.

STEP_IMPL_DIR = step_impl,fwk/web
```

Expecting Gauge to look in both these directories relative to project folder for steps, but when running I get this:

```
"can not load implementations from c:\project_path\step_impl,fwk/web. c:\project_path\step_impl,fwk/web.  does not exist."
```

Looks like Gauge does not parse the settings correctly or I'm I missing something obvious? I've tried a few different combinations, but Gauge doesn't seem to register the 'comma-separator' and is treating the whole line as a single path.

Comment: This would be a bug in `gauge-python`. please raise an issue : https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-python/issues/new.

Comment: This should be fixed as part of https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-python/issues/134